# SharpSVN - SvnLookClient.GetPropertyList - Show Inherited Properties?

Tags: svn, sharpsvn

The `svnlook` command has a `--show-inherited-props` option that will include the inherited properties of the path specified.

With SharpSVN, this SVN command is wrapped by a method in the  `SvnLookClient` class called `GetPropertyList`. One of the arguments is a `SvnLookPropertyListArgs` object, but there doesn't seem to be a property that I can set that is the equivalent of `--show-inherited-props`.

I see in the `SvnClient` class that there is a `GetInheritedPropertyList` method, but I cannot use this as I am performing this operation on the repository itself, and not a working copy because this is being used in a pre-commit hook application.

Is there a way to get `SvnLookClient.GetPropertyList` to also return inherited properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can confirm all points. I'm checking what I can do to implement the missing pieces.

The next 1.9 build will already have the option of using a repository location for `SvnClient.InheritedPropertyList` by adding the missing overloads with SvnTarget arguments.

After that I will probably add a similar function to the SvnLookClient, as the current function doesn't allow the same property for multiple paths.

Once I'm done I'll backport these changes to 1.8.x.

Comment: Thanks Bert! When will the next build be available?

Comment: A new build is available for 1.8.x and 1.9.x-rc now on http://sharpsvn.net/daily and in NuGet.